# How to change primaryButton color in amcharts5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts, amcharts5

I'm trying to change the color of zoomOut button or so called "primaryButton" in amcharts5. However digging through documentation i couldn't find anything that works.

```
var root = am5.Root.new(divId);
root._logo.dispose();

var fpTheme = am5.Theme.new(root);

fpTheme.rule("Label").setAll({
    fontSize: "1rem",
    fill: am5.color(0x97a0b4)
    // fill: am5.color(0x777777)
    // minGridDistance: 30
});

fpTheme.rule("LineSeries").adapters.add("stroke", function(stroke, target) {
    // console.log(stroke);
    // return am5.color(0x4CAF50);
    return am5.color(0x4ac445);
});

// this below doesn't work. The above code works just fine.

fpTheme.rule("Button").setAll({
    minus: {
        fill: am5.color(0x4ac445)
    }
});

fpTheme.rule("Graphics").setAll({
    minus: {
        fill: am5.color(0x4ac445)
    }
});

root.setThemes([
    am5themes_Animated.new(root),
    fpTheme
]);
```

Clicking on zoomOut button does show that green color "0x4ac445" but the button is still blue like this from docs https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/colors-gradients-and-patterns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked this code and it works fine.

```
// change zoom button color to red
root.interfaceColors.set("primaryButton", am5.color(0xff0000));

// change zoom button-hover color to black
root.interfaceColors.set("primaryButtonHover", am5.color(0x000000));
```